# Does a Dread Weapon penalize attacks on a critical?

Tags: dnd-4e

Dread Weapon:

> Property
>   On a critical hit the target takes the weapon’s enhancement bonus as a penalty to defenses and checks until the end of your next turn.

Is an attack a "check" for purposes of this penalty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems **yes** because of attacks are (as you already figured) checks.

From the *Rules Compendium*, page 22 and 23.

> Does a sword swing hurt the dragon or just bounce off its iron-hard scales? Will the ogre believe an outrageous bluff, or can a character swim across a raging river?
>   [...]
>   This simple rule governs most Dungeons & Dragons play. Three types of come up in most session of the game: attack rolls, skill checks and ability checks.
>   [...]

And again, at page 24.

> An attack roll is a kind of check that occurs in every battle, where the target number for the check is the defense of a target.
>   [...]

Note that, conversely, saving throws are not checks (in 4th edition). They are a simple d20 roll that is succeeded on 10 or more. They don't get modifiers from level or ability bonuses.

Comment: Oddly, saving throws aren't checks in 3.5 either even though they get bonuses and are set against different DCs. But then, neither are attack rolls in 3.5.